# Is it possible to change the duplicate target's scheme name,it's product name at a time?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I'm working on targets.I know how to change the duplicate target's scheme name and product's name also.But my question is if i change duplicate target's name then  will it change product name also.Is it possible to do like that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I tried the same and it didn't change. You will have to change it manually by selecting your target, and in Build Settings, search for 'Product Name' and change it from there. Also, try changing the setting from Simulator to iOS Device (the setting beside the active scheme). That changed the product name to the new name, else for simulator it would continue to show the previous name. HTH.